# How do I exclude an architecture with cfg?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

I'm working on a project which should target wasm, but some functionality will not be supported.

It looks like I can conditionally include a function in this way:

```rs
#[cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")]
fn my_func() { ... }
```

Or conditionally call it like so:

```rs
if cfg!(target_arch = "wasm32") {
    my_func();
} else {
    ...
}
```

But how can I conditionally *exclude* a declaration or a block of code on wasm?

I.e. I am looking for something similar to `#ifndef` in c macros:

```
#ifndef WASM
native_only_func();
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To negate condition use `#[cfg(not(condition))]`. You can read more about conditional compilation in [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) section of The Rust Reference.